# How do I update an old iMac (early 2008)?

Tags: macos, mac, imac

I have an old iMac (8,1 early 2008), 2.8 ghz Intel core 2 Duo, 2GB RAM, 24 inch, running OSX 10.5.80.

I'd like to know how and whether I can update it to the latest OSX.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google search might have helped you.

You can't update directly from Leopard to Mavericks. Either you install Snow Leopard first and then update to Mavericks, or you can do a fresh install (you will still need a mac running at least Snow Leopard for this).
Here is an article on the topic:http://www.macworld.com/article/2056564/how-to-install-mavericks-over-leopard.html

In case you were just wondering about hardware specifications: iMacs from mid-2007 and newer can run OSX Mavericks. Apple support states that you can run Mavericks on 2GB RAM, but I would recomment getting at least 4GB.
https://support.apple.com/kb/ht5842